# Transpose specific columns to rows using python pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have here an example DF:

```
+---+---------+----+---------+---------+-------------+-------------+
|id | company |type|rev2016  | rev2017 | main2016    |  main2017   |
+---+---------+----+---------+---------+-------------+-------------+
| 1 | google  |web | 100     |  200    |  55         |     66      |
+---+---------+----+---------+---------+-------------+-------------+
```

And I want this output:

```
+---+---------+----+-------------+------+------+
|id | company |type| Metric      | 2016 | 2017 |   
+---+---------+----+-------------+------+------+
| 1 | google  |web | rev         | 100  |  200 |   
| 1 | google  |web | main        |  55  |  66  |  
+---+---------+----+-------------+------+------+
```

What I am trying to achieve is transposing revenue and maintenance columns to rows with new column 'Metric'. I am trying pivoting no luck so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can construct an array of structs from the columns, and then explode the arrays and expand the structs to get the desired output.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

struct_list = [
    F.struct(
        F.lit('rev').alias('Metric'),
        F.col('rev2016').alias('2016'),
        F.col('rev2017').alias('2017')
    ),
    F.struct(
        F.lit('main').alias('Metric'),
        F.col('main2016').alias('2016'),
        F.col('main2017').alias('2017')
    )
]

df2 = df.withColumn(
    'arr',
    F.explode(F.array(*struct_list))
).select('id', 'company', 'type', 'arr.*')

df2.show()
+---+-------+----+------+----+----+
| id|company|type|Metric|2016|2017|
+---+-------+----+------+----+----+
|  1| google| web|   rev| 100| 200|
|  1| google| web|  main|  55|  66|
+---+-------+----+------+----+----+
```

Or you can use `stack`:

```
df2 = df.selectExpr(
    'id', 'company', 'type',
    "stack(2, 'rev', rev2016, rev2017, 'main', main2016, main2017) as (Metric, `2016`, `2017`)"
)

df2.show()
+---+-------+----+------+----+----+
| id|company|type|Metric|2016|2017|
+---+-------+----+------+----+----+
|  1| google| web|   rev| 100| 200|
|  1| google| web|  main|  55|  66|
+---+-------+----+------+----+----+
```

Comment: Thank for this, can i insert a for loop for multiple F.structs?

Comment: @JohnCarloVelasquez you can use a for loop to construct  a list of structs, and pass them to F.array , e.g. `F.array(*struct_list)`.